# Odoo, How to make a python function accessible in Qweb template

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, qweb, odoo-website

How can I make a Python function accessible in Qweb templates. 
Like the Python function `slug()` being used in templates in **website_sale** and **website_hr_recruitment** modules

Answer (score 2):

For qweb reports, define the function in the model. For example, you have inherited the model `account.invoice` and you want to add something in the qweb report template, you create a function like:

```
@api.multi
def myfunction(self, s):
    return s.lower()
```

Then in your template, you can call it like `<span t-esc="o.myfunction('Hello')"/>`.

In a website template, you can include the function in the render context like:

```
http.request.website.render(
    "my_module.my_template", 
    {'myfunction': self.myfunction})
```

Then you can call it as usual: `<span t-esc="myfunction('Hello')"/>`